# IndexOf function now work propertly ? Javascript ( using filtering component )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First, I know there are a lot of questions about this index, but I have not been able to find a solution for my own problem.
HelloComponent, ByeComponent are components..

Comment: Surely you just need:  let index = this.components[component];  ?

Comment: Just a small question. Instead of using this componentRef and all, why cant you use router-outlet and use 2 different routes to show 2 different components? Like when they click RenderComponent1, route them to Component1 and when they click RenderComponent2 route them to Component2 and show the Template accordingly. Will that be not a good solution in your case?

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the array are Angular components whereas you're sending strings `'ByeComponent'` and `'HelloComponent'` in the click event handlers.

One quick fix is to use an object instead of an array and pass in the object property keys as the event handler parameter.

Try the following

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <button (click)="render('bye-component')">Render Bye component</button>
    <button (click)="render('hello-component')">Render Hello component</button>
    <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(AdDirective) adHost: AdDirective;

  public components = {
    "hello-component": HelloComponent,
    "bye-component": ByeComponent
  };
  public currentComponent = null;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  public render(component: string): void {
    const currentComponent = this.components[component];

    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      currentComponent as any
    );

    let viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewcontainerref-agmk2z?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I don't see any other easier way. The spread operator assignment `[a, b] = [1, 2]` doesn't work for member variable properties. You might have to individually create 20 different variables and send them directly from the template.